# File not downloading from File or PhysicalFile IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a controller that calls a service. The service downloads a file from a FTP server and the controller should then return the file for the user's browser to download the file but that is not happening. Code below:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileAsync(string file)
{
    // _ftpService.DownloadFileAsync(..) returns the downloaded files full physical path on the server: C:\Web\Images\file.jpg
    var downloadedFile = await _ftpService.DownloadFileAsync(file);

    // 1st attempt
    return PhysicalFile(downloadedFile, "image/jpeg", "file.jpg");

    // 2nd attempt
    using (var stream = new FileStream(downloadedFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
       return File(stream, "image/jpeg", "file.jpg");
    }

    // 3rd attempt
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(downloadedFile);

    return File(fileBytes, "image/jpeg", "file.jpg");
}
```

The output window in VS writes this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method DisplayStandManagerWeb.Controllers.DevicesController.DownloadFileAsync (DisplayStandManagerWeb), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult in 6924.1833ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileContentResultExecutor:Information: Executing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult, sending file with download name 'file.jpg' ...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action DisplayStandManagerWeb.Controllers.DevicesController.DownloadFileAsync (DisplayStandManagerWeb) in 6936.9755ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executed endpoint 'DisplayStandManagerWeb.Controllers.DevicesController.DownloadFileAsync (DisplayStandManagerWeb)'
```

I am 100% sure the file exists. On the third attempt `fileBytes` is even populated with the file's bytes but the browser is not downloading the file.

When I click the button to download, nothing happens but I can see the file downloading to the webserver. When I set breakpoints I can also see it hitting each return line but no download starts. I am getting no errors or anything so it's very difficult to figure out whats going on.

Comment: How are you triggering the download action from the browser? By clicking on a link, or by Ajax? I ask because you can't download files via Ajax

Comment: Oh... I did not know that. It is Ajax. There's no way around that?

Comment: Not really. The returned file data becomes a JavaScript variable instead of a file on the user's disk. If you need to trigger the download via script then use window.location.href, or window.open to visit the URL using a non-ajax request

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would have figured that out. If you reply to this thread I will mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you are triggering this request via AJAX. However, you can't download files via AJAX. The returned file data becomes a JavaScript variable instead of a file on the user's disk.

If you need to trigger the download via script then use `window.location.href`, or `window.open` to visit the URL using a non-ajax request. Or of course you can employ any other method such as a link for the user to click on, or a form for them to submit